# convert rx observable api call to kotlin coroutines

Tags: java, android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have an api call which I make from android app to fetch some data, I used to use rx java / use cases with retrofit to do the api calls, I moved that to use kotlin coroutines.

I have converted the function `callOnBandRXJava` to `callOnBandCoroutines`.

I have two questions

1 - I wanted to check if the new function `callOnBandCoroutines` is the right approach using coroutines.

2 - Also my another question is if i want test this function how can I do that as I am using `launch(Dispatchers.IO)`  and `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`.

This is in my presenter layer

```
class BaseOrderViewPresenter @Inject constructor(
private val app: App,
private val orderRepository: OrderRepository,
private val onStandUseCase: OnStandUseCase) : BaseOrderViewContract.Presenter, CoroutineScope {

private var job: Job = Job()

override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
    get() = Dispatchers.IO + job

fun callOnBandRXJava(serOrder: SerOrder, action: TimestampedAction, callback: (GenericResponse?) -> Unit) {
        onBandUseCase.execute(
            serOrder.serType,
            serOrder.id, action,
            object : Subscriber<GenericResponse>() {
                override fun onNext(response: GenericResponse?) {
                    callback.invoke(response)
                }

                override fun onCompleted() {}

                override fun onError(e: Throwable?) {
                    onBandResponseErrors()
                }
            })
    }

fun callOnBandCoroutines(serOrder: SerOrder, action: TimestampedAction, callback: (GenericResponse?) -> Unit) {
       launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
           try {
           val response = orderRepository.notifyOnBandSuspend( serOrder.serType,
                   serOrder.id,
                   action)

               withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                   callback.invoke(response)
               }
           } catch (exception: Exception) {
               onBandResponseErrors()
           }
       }
    }

}
```

Thanks a ton in advance

R

Comment: First, in which scope u wanna call ur api!?

Comment: the project is in MVP pattern, so I am calling this is a presenter layer. I am not so sure about the scope to be honest

Comment: Instead of `launch`, use: `lifecycleScope.launch()`.

Comment: BTW, do u have any references of your view in the presentation layer??

Comment: I have updated the question with the CoroutineContext I am using in my presenter

Comment: yes there are references of view in the presenter layer

Comment: when I try lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) it says unresolved reference for `lifecycleScope`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223741/discussion-between-mohammad-zarei-and-brdroid).